# Python (3.4+) Regex for template extensions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following "sample" content:

```
{% block some_name %}Some Text{% endblock %} 
Something Else
{% block another_name %}Some Other Content{% endblock %}
```

And I am trying to regex to find both blocks, first the names, then after that the sections, but am only receiving the first back from my "findall" action:

```
re.findall(r"\{% block ([^\{%]+?) %\}[\s\S]*\{% endblock %\}", contents)
```

** assuming variable "contents" is the string at the top.

So i need two searches, or combined if possible, returning me something alike:

```
list[
    ['some_name', 'another_name'],
    ['{% block some_name %}Some Text{% endblock %}', '{% block another_name %}Some Other Content{% endblock %}']
]
```

Comment: Maybe something like [`re.findall(r"(\{% block (.+?) %}[\s\S]*?\{% endblock %})", s)`](https://ideone.com/lG8Ihl) will do?

Comment: Would you be OK with a dict?

Comment: Thanks for responding, a dict would always be ok! The answer was given, so no need to respond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(\{%\s*block\s+(.+?)\s*%}[\s\S]*?\{%\s*endblock\s*(?:\2\s*)?%})'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qFZECM/2).

**Details**

- `(` - start of an outer capturing group #1 (as as to get all the match into the list of tuples returned by `re.findall`):

  - `{%
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `block` - a `block` substring
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(.+?)` - 1+ chars other than line break chars (replace with `[\s\S]` to also match line breaks), as few as possible, captured into Group 2
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `%}` - `%` substring
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
  - `\{%` - a `{%` substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `endblock` - a literal substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:\2\s*)?` - an optional sequence of the Group 2 value and 0+ whitespaces after
  - `%}`  - a `%}` substring
- `)` - end of the outer capturing group #1.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sZEOTH):

```
import re
rx = r'(\{%\s*block\s+(.+?)\s*%}[\s\S]*?\{%\s*endblock\s*(?:\2\s*)?%})'
s = '{% block some_name %}Some Text{% endblock %} \nSomething Else\n{% block another_name %}Some Other Content{% endblock %}'
print(list(map(list, zip(*re.findall(rx, s))))) # Extracting and transposing the list
# => [['{% block some_name %}Some Text{% endblock %}', '{% block another_name %}Some Other Content{% endblock %}'], ['some_name', 'another_name']]
```

Comment: If this is for parsing django / jinja templates, you should probably make sure that the endblock tag can optionally also have a name. `{% endblock some_name %}` is valid. And there can be arbitrary whitespace (including newlines) inside the `{% %}`.

Comment: i appreciate that, while i also work in those, this is not it, but still very useful! Thanks!